# Is there any way to fix the problem(any root cause) that i encounter on hovering on nodes of networkgraph in highcharts.?

Tags: typescript, highcharts

While hovering on nodes of network graph in highcharts, sometimes I see something weird.
i.e

1. when I am hovering on node, I am seeing the node replica(same color node) on the line of the node connecting  to the pillar. The Exact Image is shown in the fig when i hover. and i am not able to figure out the root cause of this issue.
2. When I Hover on any of the pillars or initiatives, the pillar which is not associated with the hovered node looks like the image shown. which is not good to watch.(all lines inside pillar looks odd)

[image]Any Inputs on this are welcome.

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-formbuilder-in-reactive-forms/

https://www.positronx.io/angular-httpclient-http-service/

this may help in understanding the reactive forms.

Comment: Please add the sample data  in your question - see: how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Is there any way to set the z-index of inactive pillar, so that the lines on the pillar will not appear.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. this is due to halo class applied automatically on highcharts. so keeping  halo size 0 makes question solved

   series: {
   states: {
   hover: {
   enabled: true,
   halo: {
   size: 0
   }
   }
   }
   }